# Ajax call always returns readystate 1 and status of 0

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying a simple ajax call. The test.php is just echoing some text. But the ajax call always returns readyState 1 and status 0. Here is the piece of code which I am using for ajax call.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function showData()
    {
        var xhr;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
        }



        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
            else
            {

                var content = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = content + 'ERROR with ready state '+xhr.readyState+' and status of '+xhr.status+'<br>';
            }
        }

        xhr.open('GET','test.php',true);
        send(null);


    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="submit" value="Get Data" onClick="showData()" />
<span id="data" ></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to call the xhr.send() method.

```
xhr.send();
```

A readyState of 1 means that the xhr request is just set up, since you have xhr.open().  If the xhr.send() is called, then the other states come into play.